# wordpress do not let user registered with info@ email and other reserved emails to get registered by users

Tags: email, user-registration

Does wordpress do not let user registered with info@ email and other reserved emails to get registered by users?

how to fix this...?

when ever user are trying to register with info@something.tld
they are getting error as Email already exists, although it never actually exist!
 Please help me!

Comment: There's nothing in WordPress core that I'm aware of that would prevent any valid-looking email address from registering.

Comment: i think one of your plugins cause that issue please provide your website link so we can give you more informations

Comment: I contacted theme support
they replied

We already know this , and this is not theme related issue, wordpress do not let user registered with info@ email and other reserved emails to get registered by users, for further information i am forwarding to our tech team for detail explanation.

Comment: Nothing in core prevents info@ email addresses, I just registered with one on my own site, works fine.

Comment: can i provide you access to the domain?
so that you can check?

Comment: I am using Listing pro WordPress theme!
i contacted Thee developer several time, but they said its wordpress issue....this has nothing to do with theme..
if you don't believe me, i can give you access...
Please help me on it

Comment: It has nothing to do with WordPress. It might not be your theme, but might have something to do with a plugin or your host. But WordPress itself does not prevent using specific email addresses for registration.

Comment: Can any one help on this question?
i am new to php
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298364/how-can-i-add-a-metabox-to-pull-list-of-custom-posts-any-two-on-edit-or-add-po/298372#298372

Comment: Thanks The issue was with hosting configuration.
Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself.

The issue was with the Hosting, they altered the Apache Configuration, which resulted in complete E-mail failure.

Thanks for Support Everyone!